# scraping google web results not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Why isn't the following working to scrape google's search results?

It's failing on trying to open the response throwing a `HTTPError`. I've looked at other questions and as far as I can tell I've done the encoding etc properly.

I know i  haven't included catching errors etc, this is just a minified version.

```
def scrape_google(query):

    url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&"
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    search = urllib.parse.urlencode({'q': " ".join(term for term in query)})
    b_search = search.encode("utf-8")
    response = urllib.request.Request(url, b_search, headers)
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(response)
```

Comment: Is that url supposed to work in a browser?  I get a 404.

Comment: `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=searchterm` works for me. I accidentally put  a `.` instead of a `/` in the post, but I am using this correctly and I have corrected the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not working because the return of that URL is in the JSON format.  If you take that URL and put in a search term such as this:

> http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=bingo

You will get back the results in a JSON format which is not what beautifulsoup is set up to handle.  (but it is a lot nicer than scraping)

```
{"responseData": 
     {"results":
   [{"GsearchResultClass":"GwebSearch","unescapedUrl":"http://www.pogo.com/games/bingo-luau","url":"http://www.pogo.com/games/bingo-

//etc
```

**Edited to add:**

Using requests:

```
url = ('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=bingo')
resp = requests.get(url)
print(resp.content)
```

generates:

```
b'{"responseData": {"results":[{"GsearchResultClass":"GwebSearch","unescapedUrl":"http://www.pogo.com/games/b...
//etc
```

Comment: You'll probably find it easier to use the `requests` library.

Comment: `requests` is a much better alternative. Also to read json data you can call  `response.json()` which is shorter & sweeter

Answer (score 0):

- Just like people said in the comments, `requests` library (and (*if needed*) in combination with `beautifulsoup`) is better. I answered on question about ***scraping google search results*** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66823438/15164646).
- Alternatively, you can use third-party [Google Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free trial.

Check out the [**playground**](https://serpapi.com/playground) to test.

Code to integrate (*say you want to scrape title, summary and a link*):

```
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
    "engine": "google",
    "q": "best lasagna recipe ever",
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result in results["organic_results"]:
   print(f"Title: {result['title']}\nSummary: {result['snippet']}\nLink: {result['link']}")
```

### Output:

```
Title: The BEST Lasagna Recipe Ever! | The Recipe Critic
Summary: How to Make The BEST Classic Lasagna Ever. Sauté meat then simmer with bases and seasonings: In a large skillet over medium high heat add the olive oil and onion. Cook lasagna noodles: In a large pot, bring the water to a boil. Mix cheeses together: In medium sized bowl add the ricotta cheese, parmesan, and egg.
Link: https://therecipecritic.com/lasagna-recipe/

Title: The Most Amazing Lasagna Recipe - The Stay At Home Chef
Summary: The Most Amazing Lasagna Recipe is the best recipe for homemade Italian-style lasagna. The balance ... This recipe is so good—it makes the kind of lasagna people write home about! ... Hands down absolutely the best lasagna recipe ever!
Link: https://thestayathomechef.com/amazing-lasagna-recipe/
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.