# How to get Google like url excerpts in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have written a code like this:

```
#pip3 install google 
from googlesearch import search

query = 'java'


for i in search(query,        # The query you want to run
                tld = 'com',  # The top level domain
                lang = 'en',  # The language
                num = 10,     # Number of results per page
                start = 0,    # First result to retrieve
                stop = None,  # Last result to retrieve
                pause = 0,  # Lapse between HTTP requests
                safe = 'high'

               ):
    print(i)
```

in the above, I am simply getting the url link. How can I get google like excerpts for each url. Like the attached[image]

Comment: Inspecting the source-code of `googlesearch`, it does not appear possible. But perhaps you can draw inspiration (and reference sources) from the source: https://github.com/Nv7-GitHub/googlesearch/blob/master/googlesearch/__init__.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to do it with the package BUT if you use the `requests` module on python with some web scraping libraries ([beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)) you can get those descriptions with the HTML tag (`<meta name="description" content="google description">`)

Answer (score 1):

You can scrape it using `requests`, `bs4` library and `user-agent`.

Make sure you're using `user-agent`, because if you don't, your script would have a default `user-agent` (it could be a tablet or phone) which will show different `classes` and because of it you will get an empty output.

Here's a code and [replit.com](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-scrape-headingarticle-sum-linkpythonbs4)(java search result on repl.it):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml
import json

headers = {
  'User-agent':
  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win6a4; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?hl=en-US&q=best lasagna recipe ever', headers=headers).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml'))

summary = []

for container in soup.findAll('div', class_='tF2Cxc'):
  heading = container.find('h3', class_='LC20lb DKV0Md').text
  article_summary = container.find('span', class_='aCOpRe').text
  link = container.find('a')['href']

summary.append({
  'Heading': heading,
  'Article Summary': article_summary,
  'Link': link,
})

print(json.dumps(summary, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

JSON output:

```
    [
  {
    "Heading": "World's Best Lasagna Recipe - Allrecipes.com",
    "Article Summary": "Ingredients. 1 pound sweet Italian sausage. ¾ pound lean ground beef. ½ cup minced onion. 2 cloves garlic, crushed. 1 (28 ounce) can crushed tomatoes. 2 (6 ounce) cans tomato paste. 2 (6.5 ounce) cans canned tomato sauce. ½ cup water.",
    "Link": "https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/23600/worlds-best-lasagna/"
  },
  {
    "Heading": "The BEST Lasagna Recipe Ever! | The Recipe Critic",
    "Article Summary": "Dec 22, 2019 — The BEST Classic Lasagna Ever has layers of sautéed ground beef and Italian sausage that are cooked together, sweet tomato sauce, Italian ...",
    "Link": "https://therecipecritic.com/lasagna-recipe/"
  },
  {
    "Heading": "The Most Amazing Lasagna Recipe - The Stay At Home Chef",
    "Article Summary": "The Most Amazing Lasagna Recipe is the best recipe for homemade Italian-style lasagna. The balance ... This recipe is so good—it makes the kind of lasagna people write home about! ... Hands down absolutely the best lasagna recipe ever!",
    "Link": "https://thestayathomechef.com/amazing-lasagna-recipe/"
  },
  {
    "Heading": "Best Lasagna - Cafe Delites",
    "Article Summary": "My mama's famous lasagna recipe is hands down the best lasagna I have ever had in my life. She learnt her ways from her Italian friends when she lived in New ...",
    "Link": "https://cafedelites.com/best-lasagna/"
  },
  {
    "Heading": "The Best Lasagna Recipe EVER | Fail Proof Recipe | Lauren's ...",
    "Article Summary": "Start with a bit of meat sauce in the bottom of a large casserole dish or a plain 9×13 and line the bottom with pasta. Top with the cheese mixture and meat sauce.",
    "Link": "https://laurenslatest.com/best-lasagna-recipe/"
  },
  {
    "Heading": "Best Lasagna Recipe: How to Make It | Taste of Home",
    "Article Summary": "Want to know how to make lasagna for a casual holiday meal? You can't go wrong with this deliciously rich meat lasagna recipe. ... I made this lasagna for my fiance, he said this lasagna was the best he ever tasted, I will never buy frozen ...",
    "Link": "https://www.tasteofhome.com/recipes/best-lasagna/"
  },
  {
    "Heading": "Easy Homemade Lasagna {Classic Dinner!} - Spend With ...",
    "Article Summary": "May 19, 2020 — noodles – sauce (bake) – cheese. Spread about a cup of meat sauce into a 9×13 pan. Add a layer of noodles. Top the noodles with some of ...",
    "Link": "https://www.spendwithpennies.com/easy-homemade-lasagna/"
  },
  {
    "Heading": "The Best Lasagna Recipe {Simple & Classic} - Simply Recipes",
    "Article Summary": "Feb 19, 2019 — Ingredients · 1 pound lean ground beef (chuck); 1/2 onion, diced (about 3/4 cup); 1/2 large bell pepper (green, red, or yellow), diced (about 3/4 cup) ...",
    "Link": "https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/lasagna/"
  },
  {
    "Heading": "Best Lasagna Recipe - How to Make Lasagna From Scratch",
    "Article Summary": "Dec 15, 2020 — The Best Lasagna. Ever. · Bring a large pot of water to a boil. · Meanwhile, in a large skillet or saucepan, combine ground beef, sausage, and garlic ...",
    "Link": "https://www.thepioneerwoman.com/food-cooking/recipes/a11728/best-lasagna-recipe/"
  }
]
```

Alternatively, you can use [Google Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi.

Part of JSON:

```json
"organic_results": [
  {
    "position": 1,
    "title": "World's Best Lasagna Recipe - Allrecipes.com",
    "link": "https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/23600/worlds-best-lasagna/",
    "displayed_link": "https://www.allrecipes.com › ... › European › Italian",
  }
]
```

Code to integrate:

```
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
    "engine": "google",
    "q": "best lasagna recipe ever",
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result in results["organic_results"]:
   print(f"Title: {result['title']}\nLink: {result['link']}")
```

Output:

```
Title: World's Best Lasagna Recipe - Allrecipes.com, 
Link: https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/23600/worlds-best-lasagna/
Title: Best Lasagna - Cafe Delites, 
Link: https://cafedelites.com/best-lasagna/
Title: The Most Amazing Lasagna Recipe - The Stay At Home Chef, 
Link: https://thestayathomechef.com/amazing-lasagna-recipe/
Title: The BEST Lasagna Recipe Ever! | The Recipe Critic, 
Link: https://therecipecritic.com/lasagna-recipe/
Title: The Best Lasagna Recipe EVER | Fail Proof Recipe | Lauren's ..., 
Link: https://laurenslatest.com/best-lasagna-recipe/
Title: Best Lasagna Recipe - How to Make Lasagna From Scratch, 
Link: https://www.thepioneerwoman.com/food-cooking/recipes/a11728/best-lasagna-recipe/
Title: Best Lasagna Recipe: How to Make It | Taste of Home, 
Link: https://www.tasteofhome.com/recipes/best-lasagna/
Title: Easy Homemade Lasagna {Classic Dinner!} - Spend With ..., 
Link: https://www.spendwithpennies.com/easy-homemade-lasagna/
Title: The Best Lasagna Recipe {Simple & Classic} - Simply Recipes, 
Link: https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/lasagna/
```

> Disclaimer: I work for SerpApi.